3-D DP VS 2-D DP, can't seem to figure out why my code can't be memoized
class Solution {
public:
    int countNeighborhoods(const vector<int>& houses) {
        int neighborhoods = 0;
        int m = houses.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            if (houses[i] != 0 && (i == 0 || houses[i] != houses[i - 1])) {
                neighborhoods++;
            }
        }
        return neighborhoods;
    }

    int solve(vector<int>& houses, vector<vector<int>>& cost, int m, int n, int target, int idx, int tCost) {
        if (idx >= m && target != 0)
            return 1000000;
        if (idx >= m && target == 0)
            return tCost;

        int ans = 1000000;
        
        if (houses[idx] != 0) {
            ans = min(ans, solve(houses, cost, m, n, target, idx + 1, tCost));
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                bool left_same = (idx > 0 && houses[idx - 1] == i + 1);
                bool right_same = (idx < m - 1 && houses[idx + 1] == i + 1);

                houses[idx] = i + 1;

                if (!left_same && !right_same) {
                    ans = min(ans, solve(houses, cost, m, n, target - 1, idx + 1, tCost + cost[idx][i]));
                } else {
                    ans = min(ans, solve(houses, cost, m, n, target, idx + 1, tCost + cost[idx][i]));
                }

                houses[idx] = 0;
            }
        }

        return ans;
    }

    int minCost(vector<int>& houses, vector<vector<int>>& cost, int m, int n, int target) {
        int initialNeighborhoods = countNeighborhoods(houses);
        int requiredNeighborhoods = target - initialNeighborhoods;
        if (requiredNeighborhoods < 0) return -1; 

        int ans = solve(houses, cost, m, n, requiredNeighborhoods, 0, 0);
        return (ans == 1000000) ? -1 : ans;
    }
};

The above is my code that I have created for the following leetcode question -
https://leetcode.com/problems/paint-house-iii/
The logic in my code is to simply recursively iterate over the array painting the houses with all possible colors and using if statements that are in the code to be able to tell how I need to change the number of neighborhoods, then calling the function recursively.
The code does seem to give the correct answer, though I am not able to memoize it, the following is a solution that solves the issue by utilizing a different logic of checking for the number of neighborhoods instead -
class Solution {
public:
    int solve(vector<int>& houses, vector<vector<int>>& cost, int m, int n, int target, int idx, int neighborhoods, int last_color) {
        if (idx == m) {
            return (neighborhoods == target) ? 0 : 1e6; // Cost 0 if exact neighborhoods; else, a large invalid cost.
        }
        if (neighborhoods > target) return 1e6; // Invalid if neighborhoods exceed target

        int ans = 1e6;
        if (houses[idx] != 0) {
            int new_neighborhoods = neighborhoods + (houses[idx] != last_color);
            ans = solve(houses, cost, m, n, target, idx + 1, new_neighborhoods, houses[idx]);
        } else {
            for (int color = 1; color <= n; color++) {
                int new_neighborhoods = neighborhoods + (color != last_color);
                int current_cost = cost[idx][color - 1] + solve(houses, cost, m, n, target, idx + 1, new_neighborhoods, color);
                ans = min(ans, current_cost);
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }

    int minCost(vector<int>& houses, vector<vector<int>>& cost, int m, int n, int target) {
        int result = solve(houses, cost, m, n, target, 0, 0, 0);
        return result == 1e6 ? -1 : result;
    }
};

My question is that why can't my code be memoized and if it can be, then how because I can't seem to be able to figure out the same, and this revolves around an issue that I face a lot in DP problems that the logic I tend to come up with is very similar to the logic that is needed to solve the problem but it's slightly different in the implementation of a similar logic which results in a wrong answer for some reason, how can I approach problems like these and is this a common issue in DSA and CP. Is there some sort of trick to fitting your solution to be recursive in a way that it can be memoized?

Btw I tried to implement memoization for my code and it gave the wrong answer, I tried to memoize using a 2-D DP instead of 3-D and only kept track of the target and the idx variables.

Is there some sort of trick to fitting your solution to be recursive in a way that it can be memoized? -- The "trick" is this:  "If I have seen these arguments to my function before, then return what I had seen.  If these arguments are different, compute the results and store them".  It is then up to you to store the breadcrumbs that make up the function call in some structure that is easily retrievable when looking up if the call was previously made with those arguments.

is this a common issue in DSA and CP -- Also, you should spell out what is meant by "DSA" and "CP", because those terms have specific meanings on StackOverflow (Digital Signature Algorithm, and the "cp" Unix copy command, respectively).

DSA - Data Structures & Algorithms - Leetcode,
CP - Competitive Programming - Codeforces,
How do you suggest I memoize the above code though, the issue I am running into is that creating a 2-D DP that tracks the target and the idx is giving the wrong answer and a 3-D DP that tracks the tCost as well is exceeding the memory limit

It sounds like you should step away from this particular problem, and go take the time to study Dynamic Programming. This kind of study will pay off incredibly. Unfortunately, there are no quick tricks to learning algorithm design at a fundamental level. The way to do it is to find a good book, for example Introduction to Algorithms (CLRS) by Cormen et al., and then carefully work through the book and solve problems. For example, Dynamic Programming is covered in chapter 15 of CLRS. Fortunately for you, MIT OCW offers two excellent courses, the introductory 6.006, and the more advanced 6.046, which go very well with this book. Depending on your tastes, you may like the 2005 offering for 6.046, which was taught by Dr. Leiserson, one of the authors.
If you study the material, you will learn that generally, the first step in a DP problem is to characterize the structure of an optimal solution. Then you define the value of the solution using a recurrence relation. This is done away from a computer, with pencil and paper. Those two steps can be non-trivial. However, once you are done, you have a provably correct formulation, and writing the algorithm for a computer is usually remarkably simple. What is the recurrence relation for your problem here?
